# Why is the counter incrementing?

Tags: c++, recursion

When I run this code the output is:

```
hello5
hello4
hello3
hello2
hello1
0
1
2
3
4
```

I understand up until `hello1` but i dont know why it is incrementing. Can someone explain this to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void myFunction( int counter)
{
    if(counter == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        cout << "hello" << counter << endl;
        myFunction(--counter);
        cout << counter << endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    myFunction(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not incrementing, you're just printing the value after the recursive call:

```
   cout<<"hello"<<counter<<endl;
   myFunction(--counter);
   cout<<counter<<endl; // <--- here
```

Since the parameter is passed by value, the local variable is not modified inside the recursive call. I.e. you're passing a copy of `--counter`. So after the call, no matter how `counter` is modified inside it, you'll get the ex counter.

Answer (score 3):

You go like this:

```
    m1:Print "hello 5",
        m2:Print "hello 4",
              m3:Print "hello 3",
                   m4:Print "hello 2"
                        m5:Print "hello 1"
                             m6: -- RETURNS
                        m5:Print "0" --  -- FUNCTIONS CONTINUES AND ENDS
                   m4:Print "1" -- FUNCTIONS CONTINUES AND ENDS
              m3:Print "2" -- FUNCTIONS CONTINUES AND ENDS
        m2:Print "3" -- FUNCTIONS CONTINUES AND ENDS
    m1:Print "4" -- FUNCTIONS CONTINUES AND ENDS
```

So why does it print 0? Because of this:

```
 cout<<"hello"<<counter<<endl;
   myFunction(--counter);
   cout<<counter<<endl;
```

If counter = 1, then it prints hello1

It then DECREMENTS the counter (--counter = 0), so the myFunction(--counter); returns right away.

but counter is still decremented, so counter = 0 when it reaches cout<< counter << endl; even though it begon with being 1